# Why does smoothing disappear when stacking bevel modifiers?

Tags: modifiers, normals, bevel

When applying two bevel modifiers the smoothing of the first one disappears. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

I am using blender 2.83 and here are my working steps:

1. Set bevel weight of an edge ring of the default cube to 1 
   [image: Cube with bevel weight]
2. Add the following bevel modifier 
   [image: First bevel modifier]
3. Turn *Auto Smooth* on
4. The result is as expected: 
   [image: Result with first modifier]
5. Add another bevel modifier as follows: 
   [image: Second bevel modifier]
6. Result: Only those edges that are bevelled by the second modifier get smoothed. 
   [image: Result with both modifiers]

I would have expected that the smoothing of the large rounded edges is still visible.

## Update

Now I know, how to solve the task - thanks to the hints of Jachym Michal :-)

After applying *Smooth Shading* (RMB - Shade Smooth) to the cube, it looks like this: 
[image: Result with Smooth Shading activated]

In order to get rid of this shading issue between the flat surface and the rounded corner, that looks like a sharp edge, you need to turn off *Harden Normals* in the first modifier: 
[image: Result after turning off Harden Normals in first modifier]

Anyway the *Why* in my question still remains.

## Remaining Questions

1. When *Auto Smooth* needs *Smooth Shading* activated, why does it seem to work properly, when only activating the first modifier?
2. Why does it break, when turning on the second modifier? Why do I need *Smooth Shading* in this case?
3. Why do I get those shading artifacts and why do they disappear, when turning of *Harden Normals* in the first modifier?

When someone knows the answer, I would appreciate your help. Meanwhile, I will try to understand clearer, how *Harden Normals* and *Auto Smooth* are working behind the scenes. Hope, this helps me, to understand the reasons.

Comment: Hello :). Are you sure the cube has Smooth Shading applied? (*RMB > Shade Smooth*)

Comment: No, it is not. And when I do, I get shading issues at the edge between the flat surface and the rounded corner.
(Why) Isn't it enough to turn on autosmooth? (Object Data - Normals - Auto Smooth)

Comment: Nope, you need Smooth shading enabled for Autosmooth to work properly :).

Comment: Ok. Thank you for this hint. Did not know this. But how do I get rid of the mentioned shading issue? Looks like a sharp edge.

Comment: Added a screenshot of the result in the post.

Comment: Hello :). When *Harden normals* is only checked in the last modifier (Angle limit) it seems to work just fine. I encountered this before, but I'm not sure why that happens :).

Comment: Yes, that's right! Thank you :-)
I probably have to dig deeper into understanding what hardening normals does under the hood.